# Installing SSIS as a standalone service on all cluster nodes

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2017

Good Morning All,

I am trying to install SSIS 2017 on my cluster nodes in Azure thru add features to an existing installation but I am not able to install and I think it is not possible in clusters. I got a suggestion to install SSIS as standalone service on each cluster and then configure it to point to the clustered instance. Can anyone please help me how do I do that.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is your use case? You can install SSIS as a clustered resource but I don't think that's what you mean in your question.

Comment: @RaunakJhawar while installing SQL Server, the one who installed it, missed to install SSIS and now we have to do it.